# EnableLinkedConnections for standard users

Tags: windows-server-2008, mappeddrive, uac, logon-scripts

I've been having some difficulties with seeing local network maps using logon scripts on Server 2008 R2.

For the sake of this conversation, I have two users, one is the domain administrator account `admin` and the other is a standard user `user` who only belongs to the `Domain users` group.  When `admin` logs on, the logon script runs, a log file tells me that `net use` was successful, and in explorer I can see the mapped drives.  When the standard `user` logs in, I know the script runs (via examination of a log file), and the `net use` commands complete successfully, but I don't see the drives in explorer (or via the `net use` list or anything).  So it seemed like they were being mapped in a different context/session.  I read all over the place that setting the `EnableLinkedConnections` registry key solves this problem for *administrators* by sharing mapped drives between the two contexts (fully elevated session vs. the UAC administrative-stripped session), so this didn't seem to apply to my problem.  However, when I set this key (basically out of desperation), now the drives show up for `user`!

So my question is, everything I've read has indicated that only the administrators have these two separate UAC contexts/sessions, but somehow this has resolved the issue for non-admin acccounts.  I'd like to understand more about why that works, in case this is indicative of another existing problem with my configuration.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: have you tried doing this via group policy preferences instead?

Comment: Do you mean setting this registry key explicitly with a GPO or just accomplishing the same task with a GPO setting? If the former, I don't really see the difference.  If the latter, I would love to know if there's a setting that sets this key, I've already got login scripts running visibly, synchronously, and everything else that seems relevant, and the only solution I've found so far is this registry entry.

Comment: If you insist on using windows 95 era login scripts, and reg keys to perform built in functions, I wish you good luck.  The normal mechanism since 2008 is group policy prefs.  Here is an overview http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/01/07/using-group-policy-preferences-to-map-drives-based-on-group-membership.aspx

Comment: Related https://serverfault.com/questions/182758/what-does-registry-setting-enablelinkedconnections-do-on-a-technical-level